# PHP MySqli Multiple Keyword Search

Tags: php, mysql

I use ajax search in my site. The user can search through homes. I want to enable user to do an exact search with exactly the keywords he wants. But the my problem is I don't know from what the user types how many keywords I can search.
This is my query:

```
$query = "Select a.*,c.name as agent_name,d.country_name,e.state_name,g.city from #__osrs_properties as a"
                                ." inner join #__osrs_agents as c on c.id = a.agent_id"
                                ." inner join #__osrs_types as f on f.id = a.pro_type"
                                ." inner join #__osrs_categories as j on j.id = a.category_id"
                                ." inner join #__osrs_countries as d on d.id = a.country"
                                ." inner join #__osrs_states as e on e.id = a.state"
                                ." inner join #__osrs_cities as g on g.id = a.city"
                                ." where a.approved = '1' and a.published = '1' and a.category_id = '$category->id' and (";
                        //

                        $newKeyword = explode(" ",$keyword);    
                        $query1="j.category_name like '%$newKeyword[0]%' and f.type_name like '%$newKeyword[1]%' and  g.city like '%$newKeyword[2]%'";
```

it works but when user only types 3 keywords and no more.

Comment: Shouldn't you use MySQL `OR` instead of `AND`?

Answer (score 1):

use OR instead of AND

```
$query1 = "j.category_name like '%$newKeyword[0]%' OR f.type_name like '%$newKeyword[1]%' OR g.city like '%$newKeyword[2]%'";
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks the code i was written is ok. my problem is i don't know user type how many keywords. maybe 3 or maybe 5

Comment: then you can check the _count_ after explode then use **for-loop** your will get your answer as you want. Hope it will help you also.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to somehow know what the user's are supplying. E.g. what fields you want to match. Right now, you assume the keywords are in a certain order, but is that guaranteed? I suspect not if you can't be sure the user will supply all 3.

I would suggest breaking up the keywords into fields that can be determined and apply them individually to the query. Otherwise it will be impossible to know which of the 3 keywords was supplied.

Also you will want to sanitize the user supplied values to prevent malicious injection.

Answer (score 0):

For getting exact result you should use regular expression in query

$query1="j.category_name REGEXP '$newKeyword[0]' and f.type_name REGEXP '$newKeyword[1]' and  g.city REGEXP '$newKeyword[2]'";

Answer (score 0):

The best option is not to try to re-invent the wheel and just use FULLTEXT index in MySQL. Then just prepend all your keywords with + (plus sign) and search by normal SELECT . MySQL will take care of your keywords mix regardless of order and regardless of field size in your database.